# python - Download files and rename them based on csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, urllib

I have a csv file which I created with Google Sheets. It has two columns: column A for file links and column B for names. I found this code on the website to use:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

with open('c:\\links.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        fileurl = row[0]
        filename = row[1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(fileurl, "E:\\" + filename)`
```

But it only downloads the last row of the csv file.
I am using Python 3, and I am new to coding.

Comment: Because you don't have your `urllib.request` inside the `for` loop. `filename` will take many different values _within_ the loop, but you only get to see the last one currently.

Answer (score 0):

As each iteration of the loop you override the last assignment, therefore you get the last row into your variables after the loop ends.

You can retrieve the url inside the loop, and continue with the requested logic, this way, each row will request the relevant url.

After requesting each url, i'd suggest to store it in a list, so after the loop ends, you will have all the results in a list called `res`

```
import csv
import urllib.request
res = []
with open('c:\\links.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        fileurl = row[0]
        filename = row[1]
        res.append(urllib.request.urlretrieve(fileurl, "E:\\" + filename))
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because it filename and fileurl variables are updated each time and when they get out of the loop, they contain the last row. To process each of the rows, add the last line in the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure how this adds anything to the answer already left 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Move the call to `urllib.request.ulrretrieve` into the loop. I think this will have the effect closest to what you anticipated. With each iteration, the `fileurl` and `filename` variables will change to match the entries in your .csv.

```
import csv
with open('c:\\links.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        fileurl = row[0]
        filename = row[1]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(fileurl, "E:\\" + filename)
```